# Capture class in Codenme one

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to create an application using codename one, the application is meant to record voice and send the file to a server, i just created the voice recording part of the application, by adding a button to my form that when i clicked on the button it should start recording. It seems to be working quite fine but i want to know when and how it stops, it just seems to go on without stopping.

```
public void start() {
    if(current != null){
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    Form hi = new Form("Voice Capture");
    Button capture = new Button("Start Capture");
    capture.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            Capture.captureAudio(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    String path = (String) evt.getSource();
                    if(path != null)
              {
                    Dialog.show("Success", "You have successfulyy captured an audio file, The path ofthe file is " + path, "OK", null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                  Dialog.show("ERROR", "You canceled the voice recording ", "OK",null);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
    hi.addComponent(capture);

    hi.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should stop when the user dismisses the record window or presses the stop button in the recorder.

You can also record without the UI and have more control by using the media API:

```
Media media = MediaManager.createMediaRecorder(filePath, MediaManager.getAvailableRecordingMimeTypes()[0]);
media.play();
```

Notice `play()` is part of the media API and really means start recording.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Shai, what i wanted was my own type of recorder that i can time and make it work my own way. And I think i was able to do that, thought of pasting it here should in case it will help someone.

```
Media media;
    String p;
    String filename;
    private void doRecord()
    {

        // initites devices microphone and do the recording until it is stopped.
        p = getTempFileName();
       try{

            media = MediaManager.createMediaRecorder(p,MediaManager.getMediaRecorderingMimeType());
            media.play();
       }catch (IOException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

    private String getTempFileName() {
        String[] roots = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getRoots();
        // iOS doesn't have an SD card
        String root = roots[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < roots.length; i++) {
            if (FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getRootType(roots[i]) == FileSystemStorage.ROOT_TYPE_SDCARD) {
                root = roots[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        filename = "audioSample" + System.currentTimeMillis();
        return root + FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getFileSystemSeparator() + filename;
    }


public void stopRecord(boolean timeElapsed)
    {
        answertiming.cancel();
        media.pause();
        media.cleanup();
        if(timeElapsed)
           Dialog.show("SUCCESS","Your time is up system has saved your answer, The file path for the recording is " + p, "OK",null);
        else
           Dialog.show("SUCCESS","You have successfully answered the question System has saved your answer, The file path for the recording is " + p, "OK",null);
    }



UITimer answertiming;
    Label timeLabel;
    public void startRecord()
    {
        i = 30;
        timing.cancel();

        Form record = new Form();
        record.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        timeLabel = new Label("00:30");
        TextArea questionLabel = new TextArea("Question: " + question_text);
        questionLabel.setEditable(false);
        Button doneButton = new Button("DONE");

        doneButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                stopRecord(false);

            }
        });

        Container c = new Container();
        c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        c.addComponent(BorderLayout.WEST,questionLabel);
        c.addComponent(BorderLayout.EAST, timeLabel);

        record.addComponent(BorderLayout.NORTH,c);
        record.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH,doneButton);

        answertiming = new UITimer(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
               i--;
               timeLabel.setText("00:" + i);
               if(i == 0)
               {
                   stopRecord(true);
               }
            }
        });
        answertiming.schedule(1000, true, record);
        record.show();
        doRecord();
    }
```

It is an interview application that has question and the user answer is recorded and later sent to the server(i removed the part of sending to the server). If the user stops the application the recording itself it stops and saves the file but if not after 30 seconds it stops itself.

**NOTE**: to listen to the file you might need to edit the file name and add .amr to the end of it.